# Java memory model - what exactly is flushed to memory on crossing memory barrier?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

I think I understand the happened-before relationship for single variables. If I write a volatile field, all subsequent reads of this field will contain this new value. Writing a `volatile` crosses the memory barrier and flushes new value to main memory.

I still am not clear on what happens in all other cases - for instance `Thread.start()`, `synchronized` or new locks in `java.util.concurrent`. What does it mean that they also cross memory barrier? What data is flushed from local cache to main memory? In other words, **what is the scope of the crossing**?

Is *everything* always flushed? Now back to `volatile`, does it flush more than just the single `volatile` field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a memory barrier is crossed JVM synchronizes all locally (in context of the current thread) cached variables with the main memory. Besides that, it removes any locally cached data that is marked as dirty in the main memory.

Regarding the volatile - yes, it also synchronizes everything locally cached with the main memory, not only the single volatile field (since 1.5)

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile_java_5.shtml

Comment: Also, you should mention that it removes any cached storage that is dirty in central memory.  Sorry to be nit picky.  This is a good question.

Comment: @Gray could you please elaborate (or provide link) on dirty cached storage in main memory? What is it?

Comment: @Konrad Eugene's answer is spot on.  I was just trying to get him to mention that when a memory barrier is crossed, the synchronization happens in both directions.  Or at least if synchronization from main memory to local cache does _not_ happen at least all local caches that are dirty in main memory are invalidated.

Comment: AFAIK, It makes sure that dirty data is in a cache consistent state. It doesn't have to go all the way to main memory.  On x86/x64 it also stops the cpu pipeline which can have a performance impact.